# Dynamic Command Generation in Batch

Tags: batch-file, datastage

i'm trying to generate a dynamic command for datastage using a bat file, but i think i'm missing something.

The command "variation" is taken by reading a .txt file.

Here the code:

```
SET PATH_Classic=C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic
CD %PATH_Classic%
SET /P INV_ID=Type the invocation ID : 
ECHO %INV_ID%
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (%1) do (
SET FLOW=%%G
SET JOBNAME=****_****_**_***_%FLOW%_***_***.%INV_ID%
SET STAGENAME=ReadFile_%FLOW%
dsjob -domain NONE -user ******* -password ******* -server ****** -linkinfo ****** %JOBNAME% %STAGENAME% read_file_IN
)
pause
```

I had to keep some info private (*** stuff), but the logic doesn't change.

The problem seems to be that the variables FLOW, JOBNAME & STAGENAME are not being setted.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Comment: `setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` isn't enough?

Comment: No, this just enables it; you also need to use it, meaning to expand variables like `!FLOW!` rather than `%FLOW%`...

Comment: Great! Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You enabled delayed expansion, but you also have to actually use it, like `!Variable!` rather than `%Variable%`. Here is the fixed code (I also improved some quotation-mark-related issues):

```
set "PATH_Classic=C:\IBM\InformationServer\Clients\Classic"
cd /D "%PATH_Classic%"
set /P "INV_ID=Type the invocation ID: "
echo %INV_ID%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%G in ("%~1") do (
    set "FLOW=%%G"
    set "JOBNAME=****_****_**_***_!FLOW!_***_***.%INV_ID%"
    set "STAGENAME=ReadFile_!FLOW!"
    dsjob -domain NONE -user ******* -password ******* -server ****** -linkinfo ****** !JOBNAME! !STAGENAME! read_file_IN
)
endlocal
pause
```